# EmberJS throws undefined after deleteRecord and save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

*Solution on last section of this question.*

After six hours... I can't delete an ember-data object without errors.
I've followed the starter [video-tutorial](http://emberjs.com/guides/).
For deletion the ember-docs suggests the following steps:

```
post.deleteRecord();    
post.get('isDeleted');   
post.store.save();
```

My adapter-settings: `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;`

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
    this.store.find('post', 1).then(function (post) {
    // success
    console.log(post.get('title'));
    post.deleteRecord();
    post.get('isDeleted');
    post.store.save();   <--------- ERROR, same with post.save()       
    // App.store.commit();
}, function (error) {
    // error handling
    console.log(error);
});
```

EmberJS complains: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**
I've tried serveral modifications:

```
post.deleteRecord();
post.get('isDeleted');
App.store.commit();
```

and:

```
post.destroyRecord();
```

I've changed the EmberJS, Ember-Data and HandleBars versions, and I've switched between cdn and grunt. My current versions are (bower.json):

```
"ember": "1.9.0",
"handlebars": "2.0.0",
"ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.8",
```

The postmodel and postfixtures looks like this:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
titel : DS.attr('string'),
bericht: DS.attr('string')
});


App.Post.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 1, titel: 'titel 1', bericht: 'bericht 1' ,},
    { id: 2, titel: 'titel 2', bericht: 'bericht 2' },
    { id: 3, titel: 'titel 3', bericht: 'bericht 3' }
];
```

**UPDATE 1**

Stacktrace

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  ember.prod.js:15469 
(anonymous function)                             ember.prod.js:10127 
Cache.get                                        ember.prod.js:15509 
isPath                                           ember.prod.js:16307 
get                                              bower_components.js:8 Ember.Object.extend.serializeAttribute           bower_components.js:8 
(anonymous function)                             bower_components.js:9 
(anonymous function)                             ember.prod.js:14209 
Map.forEach.cb                                   ember.prod.js:14007 
OrderedSet.forEach                               ember.prod.js:14217 
Map.forEach                                      bower_components.js:9 
g.reopenClass.eachAttribute                      bower_components.js:9 
g.reopen.eachAttribute                           bower_components.js:8 
Ember.Object.extend.serialize                    bower_components.js:8 
g.extend.mockJSON                                bower_components.js:8 
g.extend.deleteRecord                            bower_components.js:9 
v                                                bower_components.js:10 
(anonymous function)                             ember.prod.js:12273 
forEach                                          bower_components.js:10 Ember.Object.extend.flushPendingSave             ember.prod.js:854 
Queue.invoke                                     ember.prod.js:919 
Queue.flush                                      ember.prod.js:724 
DeferredActionQueues.flush                       ember.prod.js:149 
Backburner.end                                   ember.prod.js:204 
Backburner.runember.                             prod.js:586 
executeTimersember.                              prod.js:575 
(anonymous function)                             ember.prod.js:575
```

**Update 2**
I have made a fiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wereldbolt/mam8386z/3/)

**Solution 3**
Probably, the problem was caused by version hell. I have changed ember-data 1.0.0-beta.8 to ember-data 1.0.0-beta.12 . I have made a working example on Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wereldbolt/4rrnepwe/)

Comment: You may be watching an outdated video. For instance, `commit` is no longer used now.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping. It's working now, with ember-data 1.0.0-beta.12

Answer (score 0):

You should use `post.save();` not `post.store.save();`

also `post.destroyRecord();` should work.

Do you get **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** with those calls?

if so, can you show a more complete stack trace?

Comment: I have updated my question with the stacktrace in the console.

Comment: I got it working. I have made a working example on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wereldbolt/4rrnepwe/. Thanks for helping.